# How to split a vector into two vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

After a function I get my matrix back as one vector

Example;

```
  [1] "M.                                "     "Mueller                                  "
  [3] "C.                                "     "Mueller                                  "
  [5] "L.                                "     "Mueller                                  "
  [7] "U.                                "     "Mueller                                  "
  [9] "D.                                "     "Mueller                                  ",
```

Now I want to split this into 2 Vectors, one Vector with all the "Mueller" and one vector with M.,C. etc.

Thanks in advance!
EDIT:
I get kinda weird results with split

```
test1<-split(test, c(1,2))
vorname<-test1[[1]]

structure(c("M.                                ", "C.                               ", 
"L.                             ", "U.                                ", 

    ..), .Names = c("1.vorname", "2.vorname", "3.vorname", "4.vorname", 
    "5.vorname", "6.vorname", "7.vorname", "8.vorname", "9.vorname",
```

vorname is the name of the column 1

EDIT 2:

```
structure(list(vorname = structure(c(48L, 48L, 38L, 65L, 73L, 
67L, 17L, 75L, 39L, 61L), .Label = c("Adrian                               ", 
"Andrea                               ", "Andreas                              ", 
"Angela                               ", "Anna Lena                            ", 
"AnnaElisabeth                        ", "AnnaSarah                            ", 
"Beate                                ", "Bernd                                ", 
"Birgit                               ", "BrunoHeribert                        ", 
"Carina                               ", "Carolin                              ", 
"Chris Joachim                        ", "Christa                              ", 
"Christian                            ", "Christopher                          ", 
"Cornelia                             ", "Daniel Markus                        ", 
"DavidBenjamin                        ", "Dennis                               ", 
"Elena                                ", "Elisabeth                            ", 
"Erhard                               ", "Frieder                              ", 
"Friederike                           ", "HansJörg                             ", 
"Harald                               ", "Heike                                ", 
"Heinz                                ", "Ilka                                 ", 
"Jan                                  ", "Janina                               ", 
"Janine                               ", "Jessica Louise                       ", 
"JörgHenning                          ", "Jürgen                               ", 
"Karin                                ", "Karl Heinz                           ", 
"Katharina                            ", "Kathrin                              ", 
"Katja                                ", "KlausDieter                          ", 
"Ljubow                               ", "Luise                                ", 
"Lutz                                 ", "Mandy                                ", 
"Marco                                ", "Marius                               ", 
"Mattea                               ", "Matthias                             ", 
"Maurice                              ", "Maximilian                           ", 
"Melanie                              ", "Melissa                              ", 
"Michael                              ", "Miriam                               ", 
"Norbert                              ", "Oliver                               ", 
"Peer                                 ", "Peggy                                ", 
"RalfMichael                          ", "Rebekka                              ", 
"Regina                               ", "Rolf                                 ", 
"Rosalinde                            ", "Sandra                               ", 
"Silvia                               ", "Stefan                               ", 
"Stefanie                             ", "Stephan                              ", 
"Susan                                ", "Svitlana                             ", 
"SwaantjeCathrin                      ", "Thomas                               ", 
"Tino                                 ", "UdoHeinz                             ", 
"Ulrike                               ", "Uwe                                  ", 
"Viktoria                             "), class = "factor"), 
    nachname = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = "Müller                                  ", class = "factor")), .Names = c("vorname", 
"nachname"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You could strip the white space after the name. Try `gdata::trim` or `stringr::str_trim`.

Comment: What's the grouping factor here?

Comment: Data from 'EDIT 2': `str(df)`; `'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:`. Sorry, but I don't understand - there _are_ already two columns in your updated data set. If the problem is the leading/trailing white space, you may use `strip.white = TRUE` when you `read.*` the data to R, or try @Roman Luštrik's suggestion on the data frame. If the actual problem is the data that pops out "After a function", you should `dput` that data.

Answer (score 2):

Your question includes a convenient function you can use: `split`

```
> split(myvec, c(1,2))
$`1`
[1] "M.                                " "C.                                "
[3] "L.                                " "U.                                "
[5] "D.                                "

$`2`
[1] "Mueller                                  " "Mueller                                  "
[3] "Mueller                                  " "Mueller                                  "
[5] "Mueller                                  "
```

The above will create a list of the two vectors. Alternatively, you can use "recycling" and a logical vector to assign it to new vectors:

```
> (vec1 <- myvec[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
[1] "M.                                " "C.                                "
[3] "L.                                " "U.                                "
[5] "D.                                "
> (vec2 <- myvec[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
[1] "Mueller                                  " "Mueller                                  "
[3] "Mueller                                  " "Mueller                                  "
[5] "Mueller                                  "
```

---

**NOTE:** *This answer assumes your data are in pairs.*

Answer (score 2):

You could turn it back into a matrix:

```
v <- as.character(1:10)
m <- matrix(v, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
v1 <- m[,1]
v2 <- m[,2]

> v
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"

> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "2" 
[2,] "3"  "4" 
[3,] "5"  "6" 
[4,] "7"  "8" 
[5,] "9"  "10"

> v1
[1] "1" "3" "5" "7" "9"

> v2
[1] "2"  "4"  "6"  "8"  "10"
```